# HttpRequest: pass through AuthLogin

Tags: c#, authentication, httpwebrequest, screen-scraping

I would need to make a simple program that logs with given credentials to certain website and then navigate to some element (link).
It is even possible (I mean this Authlogin thing)?

EDIT: SORRY - I am on my company machine and I cannot click on "Vote" or "Add comment" - the page says "Done, but with errors on page" (IE..). I do appreciate your answers and comments, you have helped me a lot!

Comment: @Petr: I'm highly amused to see you've never voted, either up or down, ever!. You do know you can press on those arrow things above and below the zeros beside the answers ? :P

Comment: @Ruben, maybe he doesn't read comments either.

Comment: @Benny: Hey, lets not start bickering and whining here - some people dont have time to chatter and comment all day long :D At least he accepts and that counts for something... (And he'll have the great taste to accept mine :D) Maybe we need a "read's comments" badge to go alonside he Commentator one [he already has]. Any insights to offer, Petr :P

Answer (score 1):

Main things to do are:

1. Start using [Fiddler](http://fiddlertool.com) to see what needs to be sent and in what way
2. Assuming we're talking a normal web form you'll probably need to use a `CookieContainer` with your `WebRequest`s in order to accept the cookies that come from the login request and then re-supply them when sending subsequent requests (such context is not automagically maintained by `HttpWebRequest`) :-

   ```
   CookieContainer _cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
   ((HttpWebRequest)request).CookieContainer = _cookieContainer;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

yes. it is possible.

see following code:

```
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        req.AuthenticationLevel = System.Net.Security.AuthenticationLevel.MutualAuthRequested;
        req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin", "admin");
        req.PreAuthenticate = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

It will partly depend on how the login process is managed. Is this actually done via a web form? If so, you'll need to post the form, just as a normal browser would.

If it's done over HTTP authentication, you should be able to set the credentials in the web request, tell it to pre-authenticate, and all should be well.